# Suppose that an ice-cream café has 10 different flavors of ice cream.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many different ways one can choose 3 scoops of ice-cream, so that order of flavors does not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order does not matter, use combinations. It the order does matter, use permutations.

So in this case, You have to add the possibility that all three scoops are of different flavors, two scoops are from the same flavor, and all three scoops are of the same flavor:$$\binom{10}{3}+2\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{1}$$

Comment: Could you explain how that second term has 2 as a coefficient?

Comment: @Adi_S pick which two flavors appear ignoring which is repeated.  Pick which of the two flavors is repeated.  Apply multiplication principle.

Comment: @JMoravitz if flavours can be repeated, isn't it just 10*10*10?

Comment: @Adi_S that counts if flavors can be repeated **but order matters**

Comment: Just realised that basically the formula for these situations is: (n+r-1 C r).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  Count how many ways in which all three flavors are the same.  Add this to the amount where two flavors are used and one of the two is repeated.  Add this to the amount where all three flavors are different.  Accomplish this via multiplication principle and [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: I was going to put the answer but your idea of give a hint is better.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Is it 10C3?

Comment: @Adi_S that is only the answer to one of the multiple steps I suggested.  $\binom{10}{3}$ answers the question of how many ways you can choose $3$ **different** things from $10$ distinct objects.  If you are allowed to have an icecream sundae with nothing but chocolate icecream or allowed to have two scoops of chocolate and one scoop of vanilla, you will have missed out on counting all of those possibilities.

Comment: @Adi_S No, you have to consider if there are repetitions.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois So to account for repetition, would the ans be 10P3?

Comment: @Adi_S no, $P$ is used to account for *order*.

Comment: Oh. So i kinda get it. I need 10C3 , 10C2 and 10C1. But should i just add them up?

Comment: That is one way of doing it, yes, however as mentioned in the comments of the other answer, $\binom{10}{2}$ would only count the ways in which you get two flavors but the two flavors act the same.  To make it so one has two scoops and the other one, you have to pick which of the two gets the second scoop.  You add things when there is no overlap between what they counted.  It is impossible that one of the outcomes counted by $\binom{10}{3}$ (where all flavors are different) is also counted by $\binom{10}{1}$ (where all flavors are the same)

Comment: there is a more complicated and involved method, what we refer to as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) which could answer this in a single term as opposed to having to add multiple terms, but given the nature of the question, you should still get a handle on addition principle and multiplication principle first.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make the answer to let you without doubts:

First, your ice-cream must have three flavours, but they can be repeated or different.

If the three are different, you certainly have
$$\binom{10}{3}$$
Because you're choosing three of the flavours without considering the order of how you choose them.

Then, if you choose two flavours, you must select only two of the, so it is 
$$\binom{10}{2}$$
BUT you can choose the flavours $AAB$ or $BBA$, so you must sum this two times.
Finally, if you choose only one flavour, you have 10 options to do it, so you have 
$$\binom{10}{1}=10$$

Now, you need all the possible combinations you can make, so you have tu sum all the possibilities, that are
$$\binom{10}{3}+2\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{1}$$
Now you can do the sum and get your answer.

Comment: Yup. That makes sense :)

Comment: (I know you want to upvote the answer)

Comment: Yes. But my reputation levels are too low for that. XD

Comment: @ MonsieurGalois [privileges:voting up](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is earned at 15 reputation.  @Adi_S you can however indicate an answer as accepted by putting a checkmark next to the answer which helped you most.

Comment: Yes but the answer was first made by Jessice. She deserves that obe, I think.

Comment: True that. But thanks :)